# Multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

If a have pandas dataframe with 4 columns like this:

```
      A     B     C     D     

0     2     4     1     9     
1     3     2     9     7      
2     1     6     9     2     
3     8     6     5     4
```

is it possible to apply df.cumsum() in some way to get the results in a new column next to existing column like this:

```
      A     AA    B     BB     C     CC     D     DD

0     2     2     4     4      1     1      9     9
1     3     5     2     6      9     10     7     16 
2     1     6     6     12     9     19     2     18
3     8     14    6     18     5     24     4     22
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create new columns using [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
result = df.assign(**{col*2:df[col].cumsum() for col in df})
```

and order the columns with [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
result.sort_index(axis=1)
#    A  AA  B  BB  C  CC  D  DD
# 0  2   2  4   4  1   1  9   9
# 1  3   5  2   6  9  10  7  16
# 2  1   6  6  12  9  19  2  18
# 3  8  14  6  18  5  24  4  22
```

Note that depending on the column names, sorting may not produce the desired order. In that case, using [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) is a more robust way of ensuring you obtain the desired column order:

```
result = df.assign(**{col*2:df[col].cumsum() for col in df})
result = result.reindex(columns=[item for col in df for item in (col, col*2)])
```

---

Here is an example which demonstrates the difference:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3, 1, 8], 'A A': [4, 2, 6, 6], 'C': [1, 9, 9, 5], 'D': [9, 7, 2, 4]})

result = df.assign(**{col*2:df[col].cumsum() for col in df})
print(result.sort_index(axis=1))
#    A  A A  A AA A  AA  C  CC  D  DD
# 0  2    4       4   2  1   1  9   9
# 1  3    2       6   5  9  10  7  16
# 2  1    6      12   6  9  19  2  18
# 3  8    6      18  14  5  24  4  22

result = result.reindex(columns=[item for col in df for item in (col, col*2)])
print(result)
#    A  AA  A A  A AA A  C  CC  D  DD
# 0  2   2    4       4  1   1  9   9
# 1  3   5    2       6  9  10  7  16
# 2  1   6    6      12  9  19  2  18
# 3  8  14    6      18  5  24  4  22
```

Answer (score 1):

@unutbu's way certainly works but using [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) reads better to me. Plus you don't need to worry about sorting/reindexing!

```
for i, col_name in enumerate(df):
    df.insert(i * 2 + 1, col_name * 2, df[col_name].cumsum())

df
```

returns

```
   A  AA  B  BB  C  CC  D  DD
0  2   2  4   4  1   1  9   9
1  3   5  2   6  9  10  7  16
2  1   6  6  12  9  19  2  18
3  8  14  6  18  5  24  4  22
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3, 1, 8],
                   'B': [4, 2, 6, 6],
                   'C': [1, 9, 9, 5],
                   'D': [9, 7, 2, 4]})

for col in df.columns:
    df[col + df[col].name] = df[col].cumsum()

print(df)
```

```
   A  B  C  D  AA  BB  CC  DD
0  2  4  1  9   2   4   1   9
1  3  2  9  7   5   6  10  16
2  1  6  9  2   6  12  19  18
3  8  6  5  4  14  18  24  22
```

And then you merely sort df columns :

```py
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

```
   A  AA  B  BB  C  CC  D  DD
0  2   2  4   4  1   1  9   9
1  3   5  2   6  9  10  7  16
2  1   6  6  12  9  19  2  18
3  8  14  6  18  5  24  4  22
```